# How can I get a list of devices that support a specific OID?

Tags: network-programming, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I need to get a list of the devices that support the `OID .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1` in my network. Is there a command for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such command. Basically, you should write the script/app to perform a **pretty simple discovery of your network**. Within the discovery process you'll have to **scan the IP address range** to find out if the target devices respond to this particular OID. Otherwise you'll receive **SNMP: no such object** error or even end up having **SNMP timeout**.